# Painfully slow self JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relationship table named "match_players" that has about 20000 rows. There is a column named "hero_id" which represents what hero was chosen by a player in a match. All fields are indexed.

I need to build another table consisting of all combinations of two heroes, with a count of how many times they were on the same team, how many times they were enemies, etc.

My current query takes about 90 seconds on an 8 core SSD server. I imagine it has something to do with MySQL building this massive table of all combinations internally before grouping the results.

Is there an alternative method for gathering combinations of row values, maybe in which MySQL simply scans the table, recording new combinations as it finds them? Any input is appreciated.

**Table "match_players":**

```
match_id | team | position | player_id | hero_id |

56427859 |    1 |        1 |    546107 |      17 |
56427859 |    1 |        2 |    469333 |      81 |
56427859 |    1 |        3 |    227526 |      60 |
56427859 |    1 |        4 |    193739 |      32 |
56427860 |    0 |        0 |    473923 |      11 |
56427860 |    0 |        1 |    292764 |      93 |
56427860 |    0 |        2 |    138018 |      26 |
56427860 |    0 |        3 |    326510 |      96 |

etc...
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT mp1.hero_id, mp2.hero_id
FROM match_players mp1
INNER JOIN match_players mp2
ON mp1.hero_id < mp2.hero_id
WHERE mp1.team = mp2.team
GROUP BY mp1.hero_id, mp2.hero_id
```

**EXPLAIN:**

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref                        |  rows | Extra

 1 |      SIMPLE |   mp1 |  ALL | faction_id,hero_id |       NULL |    NULL |                       NULL | 34060 | Using temporary; Using filesort
 1 |      SIMPLE |   mp2 |  ref | faction_id,hero_id | faction_id |       1 | beta_dota_2.mp1.faction_id |  3499 | Using where
```

**Update:**

Since I only need heroes that were in a match together, I updated my query to the following and it's much, much faster. I think it completes in a couple tenths of a second.

```
SELECT mp1.hero_id, mp2.hero_id
FROM match_players mp1
INNER JOIN match_players mp2
ON mp1.hero_id < mp2.hero_id
WHERE mp1.team = mp2.team AND mp1.match_id = mp2.match_id
GROUP BY mp1.hero_id, mp2.hero_id
```

I would still like to know, though, if I had wanted a list of combinations of all heroes, whether in the same match or not, what would be the best way to go about it? It clearly isn't feasible with my original query on any table larger than a few thousand rows.

Comment: "Painfully show" usually means "I forgot to index the table". What does `EXPLAIN` say? A `<` clause is usually trouble, direct matches are faster. If you're really up against the wall, maybe load all this into memory in a scripting language and process it that way.

Comment: @tadman - I added the EXPLAIN to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I only need heroes that were in a match together, I updated my query to the following (joining on match_id) and it's much, much faster. I think it completes in a couple tenths of a second.

```
SELECT mp1.hero_id, mp2.hero_id
FROM match_players mp1
INNER JOIN match_players mp2
ON mp1.hero_id < mp2.hero_id
WHERE mp1.team = mp2.team AND mp1.match_id = mp2.match_id
GROUP BY mp1.hero_id, mp2.hero_id
```

Answer (score 5):

For this query:

```
SELECT mp1.hero_id, mp2.hero_id
FROM match_players mp1 INNER JOIN
     match_players mp2
     ON mp1.hero_id < mp2.hero_id AND
        mp1.team = mp2.team
GROUP BY mp1.hero_id, mp2.hero_id;
```

You want a composite index on `match_players(team, hero_id)`.  That is a place to start.

As I think about it, the performance issue may be due to the fact that many players in a match choose the same "hero".  If this is possible, then for a count you want `count(distinct match_id)` instead of `count(*)`.  More importantly, this can have a big impact on performance -- depending on how large the teams are.

You may want to run this query to get an idea of how often this occurs:

```
select cnt, count(*)
from (select match_id, hero_id, count(*) as cnt
      from match_players
      group by match_id, hero_id
     ) mh
group by cnt
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: There are no duplicate heroes in any given match. Once one is chosen, it is removed from the pool. I'll try adding your composite index.

Comment: The composite index didn't help. Your query just returned one row with cnt = 1 and count(*) = 34190 as expected, due to no duplicate heroes. Thanks though, man.

Comment: @DaiBu . . . How many teams do you have?  How big is the average team?  Perhaps you are just generating too many combinations.

Comment: There are only two teams. Heroes are selected randomly and can be on either team. But I think I got it, man. Since I only want combinations of heroes that are in a match together, I added mp1.match_id = mp2.match_id to the list of ON clauses. This sped things up a lot. I was just logging on to update my post. In these situations should I answer my own question or update my post and just leave it open in case someone has something further to add? If I did in fact want a distinct list of combinations of all players, then I still feel it shouldn't be so tremendous of a task for MySQL.

Comment: Oh, to answer your other question, there are five on each team. The pool of heroes is 111, so the result set is only 111 * 110 / 2 = 6105 rows.

Comment: match_players, however, has 20,000 rows. I think the problem could be that the result of joining that table to itself with only a couple minor rules is a very massive set, somewhere around 20k * 20k / 4 rows. I don't know how MySQL works on the inside, but if it does in fact create GBs of data, then I could see it taking awhile, not to mention overflowing the buffer pool. It's too bad there isn't a way to tell it, simply loop through all the rows and whenever you come across a new combo, add it to a map and continue. Then report the results at the end. Or is this possible?